# POST 405 Error faced while login hosted website on vercel

Tags: post, deployment, vercel, http-status-code-405

Console error

```
POST https://hr360.vercel.app/users/login 405
(anonymous) @   xhr.js:191
e.exports   @   xhr.js:14
e.exports   @   dispatchRequest.js:41
l.request   @   Axios.js:93
l.<computed>    @   Axios.js:121
(anonymous) @   bind.js:9
(anonymous) @   userActions.js:31
m   @   userActions.js:2
(anonymous) @   userActions.js:2
(anonymous) @   userActions.js:2
```

During vercel deployment i removed cors policy error from console by updating this url

```
"https://hr-360.vercel.app/users/login," to "/users/login" 

"app.use("https://hr-360.vercel.app/users", userRouter);" to "app.use("/users", userRouter);"
```

after doing these changes cors error removed and 405 post error shown